# How to solve Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton

Tags: android, runtimeexception

I have a problem in using Float ActionButton on some devices, (**with android version 6.0.1 ,6.0,  5.1.1**)

I have tried **many** ways but still it’s not working

Ways I have tried:

1)  I’m using app:rippleColor="@color/white"  (instead of app:rippleColor="@android:color/white")

2)  Im using app:backgroundTint="@color/fab1" (instead of android:backgroundTint="@color/fab2")

3)  I’m using app:srcCompat="@drawable/you_graphics" (instead of android:src="@drawable/your_graphics")

4)  My appcompat and design support library versions are the same :

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
```

Here is my android tag :

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.mvam"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 5
    versionName "1.7.8"
    testInstrumentationRunner   "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

Here is my Error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDJyn.jpg)

```
*java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mvam/com.mvam.activity.ReportActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #155: Binary XML file line #155: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3319)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7406)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #155: Binary XML file line #155: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
at com.mvam.activity.ReportActivity.onCreate(ReportActivity.java:77)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266)*
```

**and this is my xml code** :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    style="@style/forms_main_layout_stl"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.mvam.activity.UsersActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/gray_light"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/coordinate_app_bar_height"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_members"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>



        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_add"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/orange_colorPrimary"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/main_appbar"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|left"
            app:rippleColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_add_white_" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_save"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/coordinate_app_bar_save_btn_margin_left"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/orange_colorPrimary"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/main_appbar"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|left"
            app:rippleColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_save_white" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

do you have any idea? I'd appreciate any help

Comment: have you forgotten to add error info in your question?

Comment: you're right, I add it now.tnx

Comment: can you add your layout XML too?

Comment: sure I'll add it